# how to load external flash in html

Tags: html

how to load external flash in html..?

Answer (score 1):

```
<object width="550" height="400">
<param name="movie" value="somefilename.swf">
<embed src="somefilename.swf" width="550" height="400">
</embed>
</object>
```

In the code above there is both an <embed> tag and an <object> tag. This is because the <object> tag is recognized by Internet Explorer, and Netscape recognizes the <embed> tag and ignores the <object> tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
<embed src="SRC_URL" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about which tag to use.  Grab the [swfobject javascript](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) file and let it do the work for you.

Comment: I'd recommend using this as it provides a neat way to use flash and provide alternate content if the user doesn't have flash/javascript

Answer (score 0):

[`<embed>`](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/embeddedobjects/_EMBED.html)